# How to turn off Viber 5.3 vibration?

Tags: vibration, viber-messenger

I upgraded Viber to 5.3 version last night. after that , I have vibrate on my phone when I receive new message on Viber.

There is "Vibrate when ringing" in notification setting that it doesn't select

before upgrading I didn't have this problem.

My phone is  Sony Xperia Z2 and Android 4.4.4

How can i turn off vibrate on Viber messages notification?

**UPDATE:**

Viber support :

Hello Mohammad,
Thank you for contacting Viber support.
We received numerous complaints about this problem and are currently investigating it. 
We will contact you back if we need more information. 
Thank you.

**UPDATE 2**
this problem solved in the new version

Comment: Thanks for reporting. We are aware and we're investigating the issue. We hope to have a solution shortly, so we thank you for your patience.